# Calculate Nearest Neighbor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 datasets, Fire Hydrants (3381 records) and Street Centerlines (6636 records). I would like to identify the Street nearest to each Hydrant record.

Following some SQL Server resources and tutorials I put together a script, but it has been running for over an hour now. I understand nearest neighbor may take awhile to run but it seems like something might be wrong in the logic.

```
select 

h.OBJECTID,
st.FULL_ST_NAME

from WATER_HYDRANTS as h LEFT OUTER JOIN
STREET_CENTERLINES as st

on st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) is NOT NULL
ORDER BY st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) ASC
```

The reason I think something is wrong in the logic is because when I add a WHERE clause to select only one record with an ID, the query returns a list of the entire dataset. In the ObjectID column it is all the same value (e.g., 13992) and in the FULL_ST_NAME column is (I assume) a list of every street in ordered by proximity to the feature.

```
select      

h.OBJECTID,
st.FULL_ST_NAME

from WATER_HYDRANTS as h LEFT OUTER JOIN
STREET_CENTERLINES as st
on st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) is NOT NULL

where h.OBJECTID = '13992'

ORDER BY st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) ASC
```

Ideally, each record in the objectID column will be unique and the FULL_ST_NAME column will have the street that is closest to each hydrant.

Please let me know if I can provide any other information. I tried to be thorough in my explanation and made an attempt at due diligence and research before coming to SO.

Thanks

Comment: What is `st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE)` ? It looks like a table column but then there is a parameter being passed to it so it looks like a function? Is `st` also the name of a schema as well as the alias for the table or something? In any case you would expect to get a complete Cartesian product in this case so long as nothing returns null, as every row in both tables will satisfy your join criteria.

Comment: st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) ... st is the reference to the Street Centerline dataset. h is the reference to the Hydrant dataset. 

So my understanding is the st.Shape is the actual geometry of the street centerline, then the function STDistance is calculated on the geometry of the hydrant.

Comment: Just curious: Where is the choice of distance implied here? I am trying to replicate this idea, but with a different distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN to StreetCenterLines you need CROSS APPLY.
The TOP 1 with ORDER BY STDistance inside the CROSS APPLY gives you the nearest street for each Hydrant. (Your original query was giving ALL the streets for each hydrant.)

Easier to show than to explain; it's like this:

```
select 
h.OBJECTID,
st2.FULL_ST_NAME
from WATER_HYDRANTS as h 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 st.FULL_ST_NAME 
  FROM STREET_CENTERLINES as st
  WHERE st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) ASC) as st2
```

It might take a long time to run though, since for *every* hydrant it has to calculate the distance to *every* street and then find the shortest one.

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I modify my code to match your suggestion (swapping in the correct dataset name) I get this error: "Cannot find either column "st" or the user-defined function or aggregate "st.Shape.STDistance", or the name is ambiguous." 

In the query builder, the following is underlined in red- st2.FULL_ST_NAME, STREET_CENTERLINES, and both instances of st.Shape.STDistance(h.SHAPE) 

Hovering over the red underline for st2.FULL_ST_NAME reveals "Invalid column name", over STREET_CENTERLINES reveals "The multi-part identifier "street_centerlines) could not be bound.

Comment: Hovering over the st.Shape.STDistance red underline reveals "Cannot find either column 'st' or the user-defined function or aggregate 'st.Shape.STDistance', or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: As I don't have your database I can't test it - I've edited the answer - have another try.

Comment: Thank you Edward. Your revision following my comments was successful. I could not have done it without you.

Comment: I had to google the answer myself - the trick is knowing what to search for! Here's what I searched:  "sql server select top 1 in each group"

Comment: In regards to essentially doing a Cartesian join of streets and hydrants (which is the comment in the answer of "this might take a long time"), you might be able to speed it up if you can a) assume that each hydrant is within some small distance of a street and b) that cuts down the number of comparisons per hydrant in a meaningful way. If those hold, you can use that as another predicate in the where clause in the cross apply (i.e. `and st.Shape.STIntersects(h.Shape.STBuffer(@radius)) = 1`)